# Cannot mouse cursor to second monitor through upper right corner

Tags: multiple-monitors, cursor

I cannot move the cursor from monitor 1 to monitor 2 through the upper right pixel of monitor 1.

This happens very often, more often than you might initially think: when moving the cursor to monitor 2 and you hit the top of monitor 1 before the right side of monitor 1 then you'll hit this particular pixel (by continuing moving the mouse to the right). So basically 50 % of the time.

When it's stuck at that pixel, the cursor is already visible at monitor 2 though, but I can't move it to the right (only back to monitor one and then to monitor 2 via a different boundary pixel).

My setup is as follows:

[image]

I have of course googled for quite a while to solutions, but to no avail.
Any idea how to alter this vexing behavior?

EDIT: Output of `xrandr`:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the output of `xrandr`?

Comment: From the alignment of your monitors.. The lapping bit is very low.. You can only move the cursor in this lap length.. So soft adjust the screen1 and screen2 from the pic you attached.. {Drag displays to match your setup}

Comment: @PRATAP: No also when the monitors are aligned at the top do I have this problem. But not when place monitor 1 to the right of monitor top, i.e. the top left pixel doesn't have this problem.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/485165 this may help

Comment: You could have inserted the old book us a code block so that text could be copied and it would take less memory. Anyway I can see the configuration from this.

Comment: @jarno, sorry I'm a Ubuntu noob obviously. But thank you

Comment: I meant that you could have inserted the output as a code block :)

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have same problem but my dual monitors having same resolution (1920*1080). Moving mouse from secondary monitor to primary monitor has no problem, but from primary to secondary, the mouse pointer stop at top right corner of primary monitor, within 5mm from corner. It can't be moved to secondary monitor unless I move it lower.

Comment: @lehien, I never solved it on Ubuntu 18, sorry. I haven't observed it on Ubuntu 20 though. I'll confirm once I'm near that device

Comment: @lehien, yeah, I confirmed it doesn't happen on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Thanks, it happens on my Ubuntu 20.04 :(

Comment: Today I switched to WIndows 10 and the problem is same, except it is opposite to Ubuntu, from secondary monitor to primary monitor. So this maybe monitor's problem.

Comment: @JBSnorro I solved the problem. It caused by the Hot Corner. I disabled it by using GNOME Tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the external monitor is located on the right and neither the mouse cursor could move from the built-in monitor to the external monitor in the top bordering corner, nor could the cursor enter the top-left corner of the external monitor.

I solved the problem by going to "Displays" and then moving the vertical position of the external monitor, so that it matches the bottom bordering corner rather than top bordering corner.

Ubuntu 20.04, CUDA 11.8